# Каково значение и происхождение слова "оказывать"?

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Происходит ли оно от слова "око" или связано с чем то другим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ОКАЗАТЬ** 1. В сочетании с нек-рыми существительными обозначает действие по знач. данного существительного. О. помощь (помочь). О. сопротивление. 
2. Обнаружить, проявить (устар.). О. смелость.

**Слова с корнем КАЗ**  (оказать, приказать, сказать и др.) восходят  к общеслав. **kazati** -  "показывать, говорить", причем старшее значение - это **являться**, видеться, а потом - показывать, указывать, сказать.
Таким образом, **оказать** содействие - это дословно **"проявить"** содействие.

**Приставка О** образует форму совершенного вида некоторых глаголов (оглохнуть,  опозорить,  оштрафовать, оштукатурить), центральное значение приставки - направленность действия вокруг предмета, распространение действия на весь предмет.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё с тем же корнем: **вы**казать/выказывать - выражать, демонстрировать. Наказ - поручение, наставление (депутатский наказ). Ну и **от**каз. (Приставка "от" означает направление посылания ;)

Ни в коем случае не происходит от "око".

Comment: Совет: пишите чуть более содержательно и самодостаточно. При чтении ваша мысль должна быть понятно безотносительно к другим ответам.